# How to connect the postgres database in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, rasa, rasa-core

I have created a Rasa Chatbot that asks user information and store it in the postgres database. Locally it works. I have been trying to do that in the docker but it is not working. I'm new to docker. could anyone help me. Thanks in advance

Docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.0"
services:
    rasa:
      container_name: rasa
      image: rasa/rasa:2.8.1-full
      ports:
        - 5005:5005
      volumes:
        - ./:/app
      command:
        -  run
        -  -m
        -  models
        -  --enable-api
        -  --cors
        -  "*"
      depends_on:
        - action-server1
        - db
    action-server1:
      container_name: "action-server1"
      build:
        context: actions
      volumes:
        - ./actions:/app/actions
      ports:
        - "5055:5055"
      networks:
        - shan_network
    db:
      image: "postgres"
      environment:
        POSTGRESQL_USERNAME: "postgres"
        POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD: ""
        POSTGRESQL_DATABASE: "postgres"
        POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: "trust"
      volumes:
        - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      ports:
        - "5432:5432"
volumes:
  db-data:
```

Logs: All services are running in logs and I checked in docker also postgres is running.

```
    db_1              |
    db_1              | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
    db_1              |
    db_1              | 2021-08-05 08:21:45.685 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debia
    n 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
    db_1              | 2021-08-05 08:21:45.686 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
    db_1              | 2021-08-05 08:21:45.686 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
    db_1              | 2021-08-05 08:21:45.699 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
    db_1              | 2021-08-05 08:21:45.712 UTC [26] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-08-05 08:21:25 UTC
    db_1              | 2021-08-05 08:21:45.722 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Error:

```
action-server1    |   warnings.warn(
action-server1    | Exception occurred while handling uri: 'http://action-server1:5055/webhook'
action-server1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
action-server1    |   File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sanic/app.py", line 973, in handle_request
action-server1    |     response = await response
action-server1    |   File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa_sdk/endpoint.py", line 104, in webhook
action-server1    |     result = await executor.run(action_call)
action-server1    |   File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa_sdk/executor.py", line 398, in run
action-server1    |     action(dispatcher, tracker, domain)
**action-server1    |   File "/app/actions/actions.py", line 148, in run
action-server1    |     connection = psycopg2.connect(database="postgres", user='postgres', password='password',port='5432'
action-server1    |   File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
action-server1    |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
action-server1    | psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
action-server1    |     Is the server running locally and accepting
action-server1    |     connections on Unix domain  socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?**

rasa              | 2021-08-05 08:25:13 ERROR    rasa.core.processor  - Encountered an exception while running action 'action_save'.Bot will continue, but
the actions events are lost. Please check the logs of your action server for more information.
rasa              | Traceback (most recent call last):
rasa              |   File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/core/actions/action.py", line 685, in run
rasa              |     response = await self.action_endpoint.request(
rasa              |   File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/utils/endpoints.py", line 172, in request
rasa              |     raise ClientResponseError(
rasa              | rasa.utils.endpoints.ClientResponseError: 500, Internal Server Error, body='b'<!DOCTYPE html><meta charset=UTF-8><title>500 \xe2\x80\x9
4 Internal Server Error</title><style>html { font-family: sans-serif }</style>\n<h1>\xe2\x9a\xa0\xef\xb8\x8f 500 \xe2\x80\x94 Internal Server Error</h1><p>
The server encountered an internal error and cannot complete your request.\n''
rasa              |
rasa              | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
rasa              |
rasa              | Traceback (most recent call last):
rasa              |   File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/core/processor.py", line 772, in _run_action
rasa              |     events = await action.run(
rasa              |   File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/core/actions/action.py", line 709, in run
rasa              |     raise RasaException("Failed to execute custom action.") from e
rasa              | rasa.shared.exceptions.RasaException: Failed to execute custom action.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of containers in the stack as of different physical or virtual machines. Your database is on one host and the chatbot is on another. Naturally the chatbot cannot find `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432` locally because it's in another container (as if on another computer), so you need to use network connection to reach it:

```py
# If host is not given it uses unix socket which you appear to have locally,
# thus add it here:
connection = psycopg2.connect(database="postgres", 
                              user='postgres', 
                              password='password',
                              host='db', #  name of the service in the stack
                              port='5432')
```

Also, your `action-server1` service is configured to be in `shan_network`:

```yaml
    action-server1:
      networks:
        - shan_network
```

Therefore, the `action-server1` currently has no network access to the other services in this stack. `db` and `rasa` have no networks configured and because of that they use the `default` network, which is automatically created for you by `docker-compose`. This is as if you would configure those services as following:

```yaml
    db:
      image: "postgres"
      networks:
        - default
```

If you wish `action-server1` to appear in several networks and thus be able to reach services both in this stack and whatever is in `shan_network`, you need to add the service to the `default` network:

```yaml
    action-server1:
      networks:
        - shan_network
        - default
```

Alternatively, if you are unsure why there is a `shan_network` at all, you can simply remove the `network` key from the `action-server1` service.

Comment: Im getting this error action-server1    | psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution

Comment: @Shan the 'action server' has a custom network assigned to it. You need to make the action server to be present in the same network with the database. Add `default` to the action server list of networks and try again.

Comment: Could you explain more in detail or could you share code if possible

Comment: Now it works thanks a lotttt... Could you tell me how to view the stored data?

Comment: @Shan I can but that's not a short answer. You can either add [pgadmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/) to the stack, or via shell in the database container, or by query with `psycopg2`, or with your application I guess.